# D3 nesting - inconsistent number of levels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I’m trying to nest my JSON data in such a way that I can easily make a d3 tree out of it. I’ve got this code:

```
d3.json("dbdata/getdata", function(error, data) {


var nestedData = {
    "key":"root",
    "values":
       d3.nest()
            .key(function(d){return d.category1})
            .key(function(d){return d.category2})
            .key(function(d){return d.category3})
            .key(function(d){return d.category4})
            .entries(data) }
```

The problem I’m having is that not all of the entries in my data have all four categories assigned to them. Some of them have only category1 and category2, so in such a case I would like to have only two nodes on that one link (on the tree graph). But what happens here, is that all links get a four-level structure, even if they don’t have all the categories assigned. If I have a set with only two categories (category1 and category2), I get the category1 in the right place, the category 2 ends up at the end, and two levels of empty data are created in between them.

Is there a way in which I could specify what to ignore in the nesting process (in my data set empty categories are assigned “0”)? 
I’ve tried something like this:

```
.key(function(d){if(d.category2 !=="0")return d.category3})
```

But it only changes “0s” to “undefined” and doesn’t alter the structure.

Or maybe there is a way to change the d3 code so I it will ignore those empty levels? I’m new to d3 and my code is based entirely on this example: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

EDIT:

Given the data structure looking like this:

```
   elements = [
{name: 'johny', 
    category1: 'cat1',
    category2: 'cat2a'
},
{name: 'cindy', 
    category1: 'cat1',
    category2: 'cat2b',
    category3: 'cat3'

}];
```

I would like the d3 tree to look like this:

```
        cat2a - johny
        /       
   cat1
        \
        cat2b - cat3 - cindy
```

And currently I'm getting this:

```
        cat2a - undefined - johny
        /       
   cat1
        \
        cat2b - cat3 - cindy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

You may not be able to accomplish this with d3.nest(), but you should be able to build an appropriate structure by iterating over each category of each element and building the children arrays.
Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b1s65ydL/8/

```
var root, element, key, child, j, i, catHash;
var categoryPropertyNames = [
    'category4',
    'category3', 
    'category2', 
    'category1'
]; //in descending order
var nodeByName = Object.create(null); //dictionary to hold category nodes

root = {name: 'root', children: []};
for ( j = 0; j < elements.length; j++ ) {
    element = elements[j];
    child = element;
    for ( i = 0; i < categoryPropertyNames.length; i++ ) {
        key = categoryPropertyNames[i];
        if ( !element.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
           continue;
        }
        catHash = element[key] + '-' + key;
        if ( nodeByName[catHash] === undefined ) {
            nodeByName[catHash] = {name: element[key], children: []}; 
        }
        var node = nodeByName[catHash];
        //add child to the array if is not already there
        if ( node.children.indexOf(child) == -1 ) {
            node.children.push(child);
        }
        child = node;
    }
    //child is now either the first category, or the element itself
    if ( root.children.indexOf(child) == -1 ) {
        root.children.push(child);
    }
}    

//d3 should be able to take it from here
var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
```

I also found:
http://learnjsdata.com/group_data.html to be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately that's not quite what I'm after. I've edited my post, so it might be a bit clearer now.

Comment: Certainly, edited my answer to better fit your situation. Let me know if this helps, if not I'll try to put together a jsfiddle for further editing.

Comment: So I tried to implement your code, but ran into some issues. The problem is that there's two many groups (set of nodes/links if you will) stored in the array created with this function. Same parents/children groups are just multiplied there. In this particular example, I can overcome this by calling the d3 function like this: d3MakeMeAtree(root.children[0].children[0]) but that's hardly an optimal solution, but I can't figure out how to alter your function to make it work properly.

Comment: Ah, yep - I edited the answer again. I needed to make sure that we didn't add the same child to an array more than once.
Also, added a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b1s65ydL/8/ (borrowing heavily from http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) showing a working example.